# Vue, Leaflet, Mapbox - error map container not found

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, leaflet, mapbox

My understanding is that the error is due to the my code attempting to initialize the map before the HTML element is rendered. Supposedly, initializing the map as a var in `mounted()` should fix it. I tried the suggested fix [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52047564/vuejs-leaflet-map-container-not-found), but it is not working for me.

I set my refs value in my HTML:

```
<div class="map-container-column">
    <div class="map banner-map" id="map" ref="myMap"></div>
</div>
```

And I declared my map variable in mounted as well. I tried using the suggested syntax of `L.map(this.$refs['myMap'] {` and `L.map(this.$refs.myMap {` and it doesn't seem to make a difference either way.

```
mounted() {
var map = L.map(this.$refs.myMap, {
                    zoomControl: false,
                    closePopupOnClick: false
                }).setView(regionCoords, 10);
                this.tileLayer = L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v9/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}', {
                    minZoom: 9,
                    maxZoom: 15,
                    accessToken: MapBoxApiKey,
                    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9',
                    attribution: '<a href="https://www.mapbox.com/about/maps/" target="_blank">&copy; Mapbox</a> <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/about/" target="_blank">&copy; OpenStreetMap</a> <a class="mapbox-improve-map" href="https://www.mapbox.com/feedback/?owner=mapbox&amp;id=streets-v9&amp;access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiaGlnaGxhbmRob21lc2RpZ2l0YWwiLCJhIjoiY2psNzJrdmwwMzN0ZDNxcWpwNnRteDJ5aiJ9.ENhvxwa1PF2i8f6xCcgLLA" target="_blank">Improve this map</a>',
                });
                this.tileLayer.addTo(map);
                L.control.zoom({
                    position: 'topright'
                }).addTo(map);
}
```

Am I doing somethings wrong? If not, what else could be causing this error?

Comment: Refs vs ref attribute in template

Comment: That was a mistake when making my post. It's `ref` in my code. Sorry about that.

Comment: The code should be fine. Please provide a reproduction example (e.g. on Plunker, StackBlitz, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem while using nuxt, but it applies to Vue also. Looks like there were some bugs with Vue calling onMounted() before DOM is available. It should be fixed in Vue 3.3.7. There is an issue on github [https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/13471]

Solutions below are taken from the issues page.

In older versions of Vue you can fix it by disabling transitions

```
// inside component's setup() funciton
definePageMeta({
  pageTransition: false,
}

// or globally in nuxt.config.ts
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  app: {
    pageTransition: false,
    layoutTransition: false,
  }
})
```

Or you can use hacky solution with using timeout

```
onMounted(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        // your mounted code
    }, 1)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The same thing was bugging me for the last few days. My main learning point is that Leaflet can't inject itself into the `#map` element if it doesn't exist in the DOM, which is what everyone on StackOverflow will tell you. What isn't so apparent is that `#map` doesn't exist in the DOM if - perhaps by virtue of a `v-if` on an ancestor element or use of Vue Router - the element isn't 'visible' (in the Vue sense of the word).

A good way to ensure that the Leaflet code injects only when `#map` has been rendered is to make `#map` into a component instead, with its own `mounted()` hook. That way you know that `mounted()` will only apply and run when the component is rendered, *and every time it is rendered* (eg. toggled by a `v-if` somewhere).