# Vue.js mapbox-gl Error: Invalid type: 'container' must be a String or HTMLElement

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, mapbox-gl-js

I am using `mapbox-gl: 1.9.1` with `vue: 2.6.11`.

```html
<head>
  ...
  <script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.10.1/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
  <link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.10.1/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>
...
```

```html
<template>
  <div id="mapId" class="map" ref="mapElement"></div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from "vue-property-decorator"
import { Map, MapboxOptions, NavigationControl } from "mapbox-gl"

const mapOptions = {
  accessToken: process.env.VUE_APP_MAPBOX_ACCESSTOKEN,
  style: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/satellite-v9",
  center: { lng: -73.647384, lat: 45.201385 },
  zoom: 16
}

@Component
export default class MapComponent extends Vue {
  public $refs!: {
    mapElement: HTMLElement
  }

  private map: Map = new Map()

  constructor() {
    super()
  }

  private mounted() {
    this.initMap()
  }

  private initMap(): void {
    const options = { container: this.$refs.mapElement, ...mapOptions }
    this.map = new Map(options)
    this.map.addControl(new NavigationControl())
  }
}
</script>

<style lang='stylus' scoped>
.map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100vw;
}
</style>
```

I have tried `container:this.$refs.mapElement` and `container: "mapId"` the map display on the web page, but I can remove the error in the Console:

```
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1888 Error: Invalid type: 'container' must be a String or HTMLElement.
    at new r (mapbox-gl.js?e192:33)
```

I have look into [Vue.js docs](https://class-component.vuejs.org/guide/refs-type-extension.html) and a look into similar question using also [vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52047564/vuejs-leaflet-map-container-not-found), but it is still not working. Do someone have a opinion about this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is this line

```js
private map: Map = new Map()
```

This will attempt to create a `Map` instance with no options whenever your component is created.

Just define the private property without initialising it until `initMap()`, ie

```js
private map!: Map
```

---

You can see [here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/blob/cccd8588a01c3856706d538a2221c5d9a9373764/src/ui/map.js#L404) where the `Map` constructor checks if `container` is a `string` or `HTMLElement` and if not, throws this error

```js
if (typeof options.container === 'string') {
  this._container = window.document.getElementById(options.container);
  if (!this._container) {
    throw new Error(`Container '${options.container}' not found.`);
  }
} else if (options.container instanceof HTMLElement) {
  this._container = options.container;
} else {
   throw new Error(`Invalid type: 'container' must be a String or HTMLElement.`);
}
```