# Vue 3, leaflet: Map container is already initialized

Tags: javascript, leaflet, vuejs3

I realized that there is the same [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19186428/refresh-leaflet-map-map-container-is-already-initialized) with classic javascript. However, I aim to use the `v-for` and `"'map'+user.id"`, `:ref` to dynamically create the longitude, latitude leaflet maps for each bootstrap card. I am wondering how to solve this problem in vue 3.

From the console, I confirm that each block could have a different id but the same class.

[image]

I found this post with vuejs2 [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52047564/vuejs-leaflet-map-container-not-found) when initiating multiple instances. It's been a while, now the [docs](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/array-refs.html#migration-strategy) illustrates the correct way to use `ref` in the method.

Here is the [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/multiple-maxbox-htpr7?file=/src/components/UserDetails.vue). (rendering in the localhost, though)

Here is the relevant code:

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 mb-3" v-for="user in users" :key="user.id">
      <div :id="'map'+user.id" :ref="setItemRef" class="map"></div> 
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import users from '@/data/data.js'
import L from 'leaflet'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      status: true,
      users: [],
      map: null,
      accessToken: "Token shown in the CodeSandBox"
    }
  },
methods: {
setItemRef(el) {
      if (el) {
        // reference: https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/array-refs.html#migration-strategy
        // this.itemRefs.push(el)
        console.log(el)
        this.map = L.map(el).setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
        L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}', {
            attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
            maxZoom: 18,
            id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
            tileSize: 512,
            zoomOffset: -1,
            accessToken: this.accessToken
        }).addTo(this.map);
        // this.map.off()
        // this.map.remove()
        //console.log(this.map)
      }
    },
},
</script>

<style>
.map {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I did it is to push the `'map'+user.id` into an array. Then using `forEach` to render with different maps. The error I bumped into is because the `this.map` always refers to the same instance.

Therefore, the code in the script should be:

```
<script>
  export default {
  data() {
    return {
      status: true,
      users: [],
      itemRefs:[], // for saving the unique mapid
      accessToken: "Your mapbox token"
    }
  },
  methods: {
    /**
     * instantiate the id to each user to further use
     */
    instantiateId() {
      this.users.map((user,index) => user.id = index)
    },
    setItemRef(el) {
      if (el) {
        // reference: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/migration/array-refs.html#migration-strategy
        //console.log(el)
        //console.log(el.id)
        this.itemRefs.push(el.id)
      }
    },
    createMap() {
      this.itemRefs.forEach(element => {
        // console.log(element)
        var mymap = L.map(element).setView([51.505, -0.09],13);
        L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}', {
          attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
          maxZoom: 18,
          id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
          tileSize: 512,
          zoomOffset: -1,
          accessToken: this.accessToken
        }).addTo(mymap);
      });
    }
  },  
  mounted() {
    this.createMap()
  },
}
</script>
```